# Can I send a video stream even if the user does not have a webcam?

Tags: webrtc

I am working on a video conference and I am using `connection.waitUntilRemoteStreamStartsFlowing = true;` before I do something else. It works fine except when a user does not have a webcam. Is there any way I could still send a video stream from that user with no Webcam?

Comment: I suppose `waitUntilRemoteStreamStartsFlowing` doesn't work for you because you initiated with `video: true`, which you shouldn't have done having detected capabilities prior to init

Comment: Where does `waitUntilRemoteStreamStartsFlowing` come from? That's not a native webrtc property? What library are you using?

Comment: Im using the rtcMulticonnection library. The docs for this method is here: http://www.rtcmulticonnection.org/docs/#waitUntilRemoteStreamStartsFlowing

Comment: fetch user camera and microphone details onLogin , if user does not have camera Access , then set  video = false , audio = true , so that video is visible on other user end { hint : property in getUserMedia}

Comment: I just tried that but it stills doesn't work.

Answer (score 6):

That would be a waste of good bandwidth. I'm not familiar with the library you're using, but with plain WebRTC, like in this textbook [WebRTC sample](http://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/input-output) which uses [adapter.js](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter), you can do this:

Call `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()` to learn how many cameras and microphones the user has:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
.then(function(devices) {
  var hasCam = devices.some(function(d) { return d.kind == "videoinput"; });
  var hasMic = devices.some(function(d) { return d.kind == "audioinput"; });
  ...
})
```

Armed with this info, skip asking the user for their camera if they don't have one:

```
var constraints = { video: hasCam, audio: hasMic };

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
.then(function(stream) {
  myPeerConnection.addStream(stream);
})
```

Lastly, if you don't send video, then the default is not to receive video either (silly default), so in case the other party has a camera, use [RTCOfferOptions](http://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#idl-def-RTCOfferOptions):

```
var options = { offerToReceiveAudio: true, offerToReceiveVideo: true };

myPeerConnection.createOffer(options)
.then(function(offer) { ... })
```

In Chrome you'll need [adapter.js](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter) for all but the last bit, but in the latest Firefox it should [just work](http://jsfiddle.net/esjuxm59) (note: uses [arrow-functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)):

```js
var pc1 = new mozRTCPeerConnection(), pc2 = new mozRTCPeerConnection();

navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
.then(devices => navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
  video: devices.some(device => device.kind == "videoinput"),
  audio: devices.some(device => device.kind == "audioinput")
}))
.then(stream => pc1.addStream(v1.mozSrcObject = stream))
.then(() => pc1.createOffer({ offerToReceiveAudio: true,
                              offerToReceiveVideo: true }))
.then(offer => pc1.setLocalDescription(offer))
.then(() => pc2.setRemoteDescription(pc1.localDescription))
.then(() => pc2.createAnswer())
.then(answer => pc2.setLocalDescription(answer))
.then(() => pc1.setRemoteDescription(pc2.localDescription))
.then(() => log("Connected!"))
.catch(failed);

pc1.onicecandidate = e => !e.candidate ||
    pc2.addIceCandidate(e.candidate).catch(failed);
pc2.onicecandidate = e => !e.candidate ||
    pc1.addIceCandidate(e.candidate).catch(failed);
pc2.onaddstream = e => v2.mozSrcObject = e.stream;

var log = msg => div.innerHTML += msg + "<br>";
var failed = e => log(e.toString() +", line "+ e.lineNumber);
```

```html
<video id="v1" height="120" width="160" autoplay></video>
<video id="v2" height="120" width="160" autoplay></video>
<br><div id="div"></div>
```

Parts of this is brand new, so I'm not sure how well it integrates with the library you are using just yet, but it should over time.

Chrome has an older version of this API which I wont mention here since it is not standard.

Comment: Your first link is a 404.

Comment: Fixed (Google moved the link this morning).